# How to call multiple web services with an orchestration with BizTalk

Tags: c#, sql, biztalk, esb

I have a client app that needs to do a transformation, then hit an orchestration where it calls a Rest service, make a request and return a response, then return the response back to the calling client, is this possible with BizTalk? I have the inital orchestration as a web service..

I have tried calling the web service from inside the Orchestration which I converted to a wcf web service with the BizTalk Wizard. It throws a multiple send error..

I used custom pipelines to call the REST Service to convert to JSON for the request, and convert to Xml for the response. Which works fine, its how to get the response back to the orchestration, then back to the client.

I started to look at ESB and it seems like its overkill for what I need to accomplish.

Comment: Addendum: The client will be one of many with different data requirements. I thought of creating a custom pipeline to do the transformation, but there will be quite a few.

Comment: It sounds entirely possible to do as I've built scenarios like that many times. Your question is a bit broad however. What version of BizTalk are you using?  Also please use the [edit] link rather than adding in the comments.   If you bind the request/ response port and the request / response send port to the Orchestration it will automatically correlate the message to the orchestration and receive location.    I don't think the Wizard has been updated to do restful services, as they don't have a WSDL, so you have to manually set up the send port.